# Spring Security LDAP Auth from Ionic

Tags: spring, security, ionic-framework, ldap

I developed a Back End with using Java Spring and I added LDAP Authentication with extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I can get authenticated from POSTMAN but I can't from Ionic.

My Spring side ;

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//TODO: add other endpoints like /events in order to permit un-authenticated users
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login**").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/home").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/events/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com/dc=example,dc=com")
            .and()
            .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
            .userSearchBase("ou=mathematicians")
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0}");

}
```

Login Controller;

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String home() throws NamingException {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
    return "hey, nice! = " + currentPrincipalName;
}
```

And my Postman Login;
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnZ9E.png)

Lastly, my client (ionic) side auth code;

```
 authenticate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append("username",this.state.username);
    data.append("password",this.state.password);

    fetch(host + "/login", {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
        redirect :"follow",
        headers: {
            'Accept': '*/*'
        },
        keepalive: true 
    })
   }
```

But from my Ionic side, I can't get "hey, nice! = euler" response as I get from POSTMAN. I think that I handled with CORS but I didn't figure out whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question.

I added proxy to my package.json and added credentials: "include" to post request header at front end.